# looping over a dictionary, searching for copies and appending list of copies to list

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to loop over a dictionary to search for copies, adding these copies (where they exist) to a list and then appending that list to another list that will contain all copies as sublist. For example
a.jpg b.jpg and c.jpg are all the same picture and are copies. 1.jpg and 2.jpg are also the same photo and thus copies of each, so the final list `copies` will contain 2 sublists: `copies = [[a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg], [1.jpg, 2.jpg]]`

Here is my code:

```
def deal_with_dubs():
    print("FILES: ", FILE_HASH_DICTIONARY)
    for file1 in FILE_HASH_DICTIONARY:
        #print (str(file1))
        count = 0
        copy = []
        copy.append(file1)
        for file2 in FILE_HASH_DICTIONARY:
            if FILE_HASH_DICTIONARY[file1] == FILE_HASH_DICTIONARY[file2]:
                count = count +1
                if count > 1:copy.append(file2)


            if len(copy) > 1 and copies.__contains__(copy) == False:copies.append(copy)
    copies.sort()
    for n in copies:print(n)
```

The output I get is:

```
('FILES: ', {'stuff.jpg': '06a7c9413b2a36bf78dcc981f2f6873fa9a82e00', '2.jpg': '9687f69f124876cbdb98045617c37df46e13a594', 'test.py': '41ddcacda888fbb43791825fff6855de94c1e3fe', 'dubs.py': '574c4570038820d81bcbe4cf8cdadcf9db2c7820', 'Elliot.jpg': '0a3cbb6c58ad7f9ddcd40c7c73c02c75a012800f', '1.jpg': '9687f69f124876cbdb98045617c37df46e13a594', 'hello_friend.jpg': '06a7c9413b2a36bf78dcc981f2f6873fa9a82e00', 'blade15-2020-gallery-05.jpg': '06a7c9413b2a36bf78dcc981f2f6873fa9a82e00', '.DS_Store': '980b43f31413a0e94ae62ec9e5ec546bee9fe16b', 'nnnn.jpg': '06a7c9413b2a36bf78dcc981f2f6873fa9a82e00', 'test2.py': 'e05f020b979c5f03348d85dc138f7bed07101c6b', 'blah.jpg': '0a3cbb6c58ad7f9ddcd40c7c73c02c75a012800f'})
['1.jpg', '1.jpg']
['2.jpg', '1.jpg']
['Elliot.jpg', 'blah.jpg']
['blade15-2020-gallery-05.jpg', 'hello_friend.jpg', 'blade15-2020-gallery-05.jpg', 'nnnn.jpg']
['blah.jpg', 'blah.jpg']
['hello_friend.jpg', 'hello_friend.jpg', 'blade15-2020-gallery-05.jpg', 'nnnn.jpg']
['nnnn.jpg', 'hello_friend.jpg', 'blade15-2020-gallery-05.jpg', 'nnnn.jpg']
['stuff.jpg', 'hello_friend.jpg', 'blade15-2020-gallery-05.jpg', 'nnnn.jpg']
```

Whilst this is capturing the copies (in this case:

```
[Elliot.jpg, blah.jpg], 
['blade15-2020-gallery-05.jpg', 'hello_friend.jpg', 'blade15-2020-gallery-05.jpg', 'nnnn.jpg'] and['2.jpg', '1.jpg'], there are multiple file copies, like [1.jpg, 1.jpg])
```

I've tried working through this, but I can't see why it's making a list of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
files = {'stuff.jpg': '06a7c9413b2a36bf78dcc981f2f6873fa9a82e00',
         '2.jpg': '9687f69f124876cbdb98045617c37df46e13a594',
         'test.py': '41ddcacda888fbb43791825fff6855de94c1e3fe',
         'dubs.py': '574c4570038820d81bcbe4cf8cdadcf9db2c7820',
         'Elliot.jpg': '0a3cbb6c58ad7f9ddcd40c7c73c02c75a012800f',
         '1.jpg': '9687f69f124876cbdb98045617c37df46e13a594',
         'hello_friend.jpg': '06a7c9413b2a36bf78dcc981f2f6873fa9a82e00',
         'blade15-2020-gallery-05.jpg': '06a7c9413b2a36bf78dcc981f2f6873fa9a82e00',
         '.DS_Store': '980b43f31413a0e94ae62ec9e5ec546bee9fe16b',
         'nnnn.jpg': '06a7c9413b2a36bf78dcc981f2f6873fa9a82e00',
         'test2.py': 'e05f020b979c5f03348d85dc138f7bed07101c6b',
         'blah.jpg': '0a3cbb6c58ad7f9ddcd40c7c73c02c75a012800f'}


from collections import defaultdict
def deal_with_dubs(files):
    hash_to_names = defaultdict(list)
    for name, hash_k in files.items():
        hash_to_names[hash_k].append(name)
    copies = []
    for names in hash_to_names.values():
        if len(names) > 1:
            names.sort()
            copies.append(names)
    print(copies)

deal_with_dubs(files)
```

Output:

```
[['blade15-2020-gallery-05.jpg', 'hello_friend.jpg', 'nnnn.jpg', 'stuff.jpg'], ['1.jpg', '2.jpg'], ['Elliot.jpg', 'blah.jpg']]
```